# Fail to load the App due to ODBC driver

Tags: perl, odbc, perl-module

install_driver(ODBC) failed:

> Can't load '/usr/local/lib/perl5/auto/DBD/ODBC/ODBC.so' for module
>   DBD::ODBC: libodbc.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file
>   or directory at /usr/lib/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 200.  at (eval 3)
>   line 3 Compilation failed in require at (eval 3) line 3. Perhaps a
>   required shared library or dll isn't installed where expected  at
>   M_BLACKLIST.pl line 14

I have using latest unixodbc dbi drvier.
Basically i use centos 6.

Comment: Are you sure you've installed the unixODBC Driver Manager package? Did you build DBD::ODBC yourself or did you install it via a package?

Comment: i have installed  DBD::ODBC via package

Comment: And did you install the unixodbc packages DBD::ODBC relies upon. I don't use Centos so I'm not sure what package manager it uses. The error you are getting says DBD::ODBC depends on the unixodbc driver manager shared object and it was not found in your dynamic linker path. You need libodbc.so (from the unixodbc package). Do ldd /usr/local/lib/perl5/auto/DBD/ODBC/ODBC.so and you'll see what shared objects it needs and what wasn't found.

Comment: Try typing "yum list installed" and pipe it into a grep -i unixodbc e.g. yum list installed | grep -i unixodbc. What does it output?

Comment: ldd /usr/local/lib/perl5/auto/DBD/ODBC/ODBC.so
 linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x001a2000)
 libodbc.so.1 => not found
 libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x003a0000)
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00912000)

Comment: yum list installed | grep -i unixodbc

unixODBC.i686            2.2.14-11.el6    @anaconda-centos-201106051823.i386/6.0
unixODBC-devel.i686      2.2.14-11.el6    @anaconda-centos-201106051823.i386/6.0

Answer (score 0):

Just be aware, that the latest unixODBC build will create libodbc.so.2, the number was incremented after the SQLLEN change to the api a year or so ago May not be the problem, but worth checking what libodbc.so you actually have.

Comment: currently i have using following libodbc.so :


/usr/lib/libodbc.so
/usr/lib/libodbc.so.2
/usr/lib/libodbc.so.2.0.0
/usr/local/lib/libodbc.so
/usr/local/lib/libodbc.so.1
/usr/local/lib/libodbc.so.1.0.0
/usr/src/asterisk/unixODBC-2.2.12/DriverManager/.libs/libodbc.so
/usr/src/asterisk/unixODBC-2.2.12/DriverManager/.libs/libodbc.so.1
/usr/src/asterisk/unixODBC-2.2.12/DriverManager/.libs/libodbc.so.1.0.0

please suggest me how i can solve the problem

Comment: I would imagine /usr/local/lib is not on your dynamic linker search path as the file ODBC.so requires is libodbc.so.1 and you have that in /usr/local/lib. Try doing export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib then running your Perl.